# How to use a date as the critera for an expression

Tags: date, ms-access, query-builder

I am using a function to convert a field from a number representing a date in the format YYYYMMDD to serial number representing the date:

```
Created Date: DateSerial(Left([<field>],4),Mid([<field>],5,2),Right(<[field]>,2))
```

I thought this would allow me to use a date type criteria in query building like:

```
> #01/01/2014#
```

However it doesn't act as a criteria and instead returns all of the records regardless of the date.

--Edit--

The field starts with a string of text for exmaple "20110101" and the formula converts it to a serial number like:

`DateSerial("2011","01","01) = 40544`

I would have though #01/01/2014# = to 40544 so I could add a criteria >= #01/01/2014# and it would include 01/01/2014 onwards.

I am using the MS Access 2010 query builder to build my query. There is a field called "criteria" into which I am trying to enter a value or expression that will filter 01/01/2014 and onwards.

Comment: What does `Created Date` result in? Show an example. And how are you building the query and criteria?

Comment: What is the field type of this value in your table? And can you copy paste the sql generated by the SQL builder?
FYI I tried everything exactly as you explained here and I can create my query as you expect it to work (I tried text, date/time and number for my field types, all work fine) so maybe there is simply a typo in your query.